# How to add Typescript interface for Js promises?

Tags: typescript, promise, typescript-generics

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to set types of Promises to the following code

Giving type of `Promise<any>` to **promise** variable is still giving squiggly red for **.resolve** , **.reject** and **.promise**

```
const wrappedPromise = function() {
  var wrappedPromise = {},
    promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      wrappedPromise.resolve = resolve;
      wrappedPromise.reject = reject;
    });
  wrappedPromise.then = promise.then.bind(promise);
  wrappedPromise.catch = promise.catch.bind(promise);
  wrappedPromise.promise = promise;
  return wrappedPromise;
};
```

Also, does use of *generics* make sense here? If yes, then how?

Comment: Just FWIW, I wouldn't wrap promises that way if you can possibly avoid it. I've always been able to avoid it.

Comment: I acknowledge that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does use of generics make sense here

Yes, but you'll also need an interface type for your wrapped promise. (Well, you don't **need** it, but it'll make life much simpler). Let's start with that:

```
interface WrappedPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {
    resolve(v: T): void;
    reject(e: Error): void;
    promise: Promise<T>;
}
```

You may want to tweak some things here or there, but for instance since you don't know what a `then` handler might convert the fulfillment passing through it into, `Promise<any>` makes sense for `then`'s return type.

Then it's a matter of assigning type arguments to your function and probably using a `Partial` wrapper on `wrappedPromise` since it initially doesn't have all the properties `WrappedPromise` requires (and that means we'll need to use a type assertion at the end once we know it has all the parts):

```
const wrappedPromise = function<T>(): WrappedPromise<T> {
  var wrappedPromise: Partial<WrappedPromise<T>> = {},
    promise = new Promise<T>(function(resolve, reject) {
      wrappedPromise.resolve = resolve;
      wrappedPromise.reject = reject;
    });
  wrappedPromise.then = promise.then.bind(promise);
  wrappedPromise.catch = promise.catch.bind(promise);
  wrappedPromise.promise = promise;
  return wrappedPromise as WrappedPromise<T>;
};
```

Again, you may need to tweak that some, but you get the idea.

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB0xAJgBSgHsBbYAZwgB4AVAPmQgA9IRdzlDSLr7kBvAFDIRyKBHJEANgDcIAChkAuZDQCUKmUWC4A3MNHiAVhARh5EFQFEoxKBuRad+0ckzEylFV0+86+gF9BBCIQcjBkAHcMbDwfHmQAXmQYAFcQM2BQ2jp5B3QsHAIPHhyBAxk4KCiYovivTiqwYDgpKgLY4u5KHIZk-gCAGgMRd26UZJAISM4Snvp5NIzm0PlxSVkIQbEIEzM1ctcRaMK4uYgAOnXpOSSdjbkXI5PO+svjUwjkj7MnkQC1E8XnVzhcwAALCAgO5jXxgyEgC4AI1AuHksJ4gIMwLO4wuCDgYAQ4JhoIJRPByNR6POWOOtVxcIxlFJ4ye4jAqSg0JxXV8yDgHA6IPGOUCuiAA)

You'll want to take a close look at TypeScript's definition of `Promise` to see whether there's more you want to do there...

Comment: why on earth would you ever write code that way? Serious question.

Comment: @Peter - With promises, TypeScript only helps a little bit, mostly with intelligently handling `async` function return types. The plumbing for a **really** general-purpose thing like `Promise` is very non-trivial. (And I would not try to wrap them like this.) I'm probably missing a couple of things above. :-)